# Transcribing trombone parts - mid 1800s music

Tags: transcription, trombone, romantic-period, instrumentation

I'm preparing some mid 1800s orchestral music for performance and I have some difficulties dealing with the trombone parts. It's mostly 2-part but occasionaly third voice appears (it's all written on one staff). I decided to go with two tenor and bass trombone (the instrument types aren't specified in the source manuscript). I assigned the highest voice to 1st tenor, the lowest to the bass one, and this occasional 3rd voice to 2nd tenor. My question is: should I rewrite the 1st tenor part into the 2nd one whenever it remains silent or just leave as it is and make it play only in those rare moments of 3-part chord?[image: So far it looks like this:]

Comment: There are some concerns besides covering all the pitches: whether the 3-note chord should be louder than the others, and how much you care about giving Tenor 2 an "interesting" part or avoiding counting long rests.

Comment: Is the source a printed edition or a manuscript?  What is the nationality of the composer or publisher?  What is the full instrumentation of the piece?  If the staff is unlabeled in the source, why do you think it's a trombone part?

Comment: @AndyBonner Those 3-note chords strikes only in tutti chords or passages, so I guess they mean to reinforce the whole orchestra and to be louder than 2-voice parts. As for the second concern I'll opt for the better solution from the perspective of 2nd trombone player, but without obscuring the original composer's intentions. So, if doubling the part, despite being more interesting, is something that's against orchestration common sense, than it's a no go.

Comment: @phoog It's a manuscript, and since it's a copy, not an autograph and it's unsigned, I can't give you the exact nationality, but I'm pretty much sure he's european. And sorry for being inaccurate: the staff is labeled as "trombones" but throughout the whole piece there are no further indications wheter the alto, tenor, or bass trombone is playing (when e.g. only one trombone is playing). The full instrumentation is: 1 piccolo flute, 2 flutes, 2 oboes, 2 clarinets in C, 2 bassons, 2 french horns in C, two trumpets in C, three trombones, timpani, mixed choir and strings.

Comment: @Mart33n: Thank you for additional information; you might also want to integrate it into the question, to have all related information in one place. Judging from the example I would probably keep it in one system, since wind players are accustomed to that. This leaves also the choice to them, whether to play  middle or lower note. (I guess a 2nd tenor player  is hard to justify for an occasional note.)

Comment: I might write the upper two as a single line with "divisi" where the third note shows up.  It depends on the balance you want for the piece as a whole (and whether your 'bone players understand the concept of  "piano" as a dynamic :-)